# Is it possible to simulate a navigation key press in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The latest version (4.0) of the jqGrid [introduced](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/functionality/keynav/default.php)  **bindKeys** method to provide simple keypress navigation implementation out of the box.

Is there any way to simulate the navigation key press in jqGrid to trigger its internal logic? Are there any directly exposed methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so there is a direct way. You could try to capture the original event you make with your keyboard and then try to trigger your own with something of a copy of the event data object.